# Extract multiple files at once in the terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, filenames, zip, arguments

I have a directory containing hundreds of zip files. I want to be able to select about fifty files and extract them all at once using `unzip` (or `7z`) in the terminal. The files have completely different names, so I cannot use a regular expression to match them all.

As a simplified example, I have the following three files:

```
41a02d81b1c7b6225b11908c38b820cc.zip
d581697699c4321c32b733a9678.zip
ffb7077a319b2d168d5415b0f59a9e2ba3a.zip
```

and I want to extract only two of them without typing the commands manually.

Is there a way to use a GUI to select multiple files and then export the list to bash to be processed by a command?

Comment: Possible solution (although not on same site) tell me if it worked or not https://askubuntu.com/a/1280489/1130604  (Obviously Replace the command with the unzip command, )  Even if this does not work, or is perfect (note: It isn't)  Hopefully it can be helpful for the future

Answer (score 5):

With the `zsh`, shell, and provided you have:

```
setopt auto_menu autolist correct no_list_ambiguous
setopt list_types auto_pushd no_list_beep

zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _correct _approximate _prefix
zstyle ':completion:*' format 'Completing %d'
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
eval "$(dircolors)"
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors ${(s.:.)LS_COLORS}
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'm:{a-z}={A-Z}' 'm:{a-zA-Z}={A-Za-z}' 'r:|[._-]=* r:|=* l:|=*'
zstyle ':completion:*' max-errors 1 not-numeric
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
zstyle ':completion:*' original true
zstyle ':completion:*' prompt 'correct> '
zstyle ':completion:*' select-prompt '%SScrolling active: current selection at %p%s'
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose true
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select=2
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit -i
```

in your `~/.zshrc` (note that not all of those are relevant here; and were obtained as a result of running `compinstall` to tune completion), then you can type:

```
$ for f (*.zipTab
```

At that point, that will list the `zip` files in the current directory and let you select them with arrow keys and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

If instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select an entry, you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, it will insert the current entry but also let you carry on selecting more files.

On the last, file, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then you can finish the command such as:

```
for f (file1.zip file2.zip) unzip -d $f:r $f
```

Which for each file will unzip it into a directory with the same name but without the `.zip` extension (`file1.zip` in `file1/`, `file2.zip` in `file2/`, etc).

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know zsh had a TUI-like facility.

Comment: Me neither, @Stéphane Chazelas thanks for this answer*  -  extremely elegant!

Answer (score 5):

In `zsh`/`bash`/`ksh93` (or with GNU `printf`), you could do:

```
$ printf 'unzip %q\n' ./*.zip > commands
$ vi commands
```

And within `vi` (or your favourite text editor), remove the lines for the files you don't want to unzip. Save the changes. Then run:

```
zsh -x ./commands
```

(replace `zsh` with your favourite shell, preferably the one you ran the `printf` command from).

---

Instead of storing `unzip 'file.zip'` commands in that file, you can also store just the files:

```
printf '%s\n' ./*.zip > files
```

and edit that `files`.

And assuming none of the file names contain newline characters and with GNU `xargs`:

```
xargs -d '\n' -tr0a files -n1 unzip
```

to unzip them.

---

A similar approach with zsh would be to do something similar, but instead of editing a file, you edit a variable with the `vared` builtin:

```
list=(*.zip)
```

To seed the `$list` array with the zip files in the current directory.

```
vared list
```

to `ed`it that `var`iable, removing the entries you don't want to unzip. Then:

```
for f ($list) unzip -d $f:r $f
```

To unzip all the files in `$list`.

Comment: Is it possible for `unzip` to read arguments from a file?

Comment: @Emmav, you'd typically use `xargs` for that. See edit.

Comment: `xargs` doesn't work in this case because `unzip` et al. accept only one argument.

Comment: @EmmaV. Thanks. Sorry, my bad. I forgot the `-n1`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [iselect](http://www.ossp.org/pkg/tool/iselect/) for this.   Give it a list of things (filenames or whatever), and it pops up a curses dialog box in your terminal allowing you to select one or more items.

It returns a list of selected items, and you can do what you want them them.

I've used it several times in scripts over the years for tasks similar to yours.

Alternatively, [Midnight Commander](https://midnight-commander.org/) is a full-featured text-mode file browser that lets you navigate directories (and "enter" zip files, i.e. navigate them as if they're a directory), has built in file viewers and simple editor, and lets you select file(s) to use with built-in features or pass as args to external programs.

Midnight Commander is well-known and packaged for most, if not all, distros.  `iselect` is a bit more obscure.  On Debian, they're packaged as `mc` and `iselect` respectively.

Comment: I've tried using `mc`. I can create a text file of selected files by using `Ctrl-x` `t`, then editing the line to add `printf '%s\n' ... > outputFile`, but I cannot get each file on a new line automatically. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: `printf '%s\n'` is the way I'd do it, but why would you need to?  your script can just have a loop like `for f in "$@"; do .....something with "$f"..... ; done` to iterate over the filenames?    BTW, note that \n as a filename separator isn't 100% safe - \n is a valid character in filenames (and isn't all that uncommon, especially if the filenames came from windows or mac, or other people trying to make the names on their desktop icons readable)

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a terminal, the natural approach would be to view the directory in Emacs `dired` mode (`C-x d`).  You can then select files to operate on with `m` (or select a group by wildcard with `% m`) and deselect with `u`.

Once you've made your selection, you can run a command on the selected files with `!`.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of thing is exactly what the X select/paste conventions are for.

```
find that/dir; while read; do whatever with $REPLY; done
```

and then tripleclick to select a line from the listing out of your scrollback buffer and middlemouse click to paste it into the terminal *without losing your place in the list*.

Or you can fire up any editor worth the name, emacs has its builtin dired, vim has its builtin netrw, and mark the files you want, then do whatever with the marked files.

Or you can generate all the commands into a file and edit out the ones you don't want:

```
find that/dir -iname \*.zip -printf '7z x %p\n' | vim -R -
```

then pipe the buffer through a shell.

Answer (score 0):

## tried `find`?

`find ./ -type f -iname "*.7z" -exec UNZIP_COMMAND_HERE {} \;`

edit:

`find ./ -type f -iname "[a-z].7z" -exec UNZIP_COMMAND_HERE {} \;`

Comment: I cannot use `find` for this. I would need to match arbitrary file names; not all files or a regex.

Comment: Oh  thank you for pointing that out - will edit post.   

Note: what do you mean by arbitrary filenames? like, filenames with no  extension ?

Comment: I mean file names that do not match the same pattern or regex, so they have to be entered manually.

Comment: @EmmaV Can you post some example files (filenames)?

Comment: Added an example to the question.

Comment: @EmmaV okay, if it wouldn't be `find` - would it look something like that? (updated post) (using find just to try to grasp what you mean by you can't use find here, since they have a extension .zip -  which is easily detectable) (reason I ask is to just get a **clear picture of what you have in mind as the final result**        
EDIT:  **So you mean - you want to enter a number of how many it would find?**  wait, checked your post.

Comment: The two commands you've written would not match two of the files only. `find` is not suitable for this task.

Comment: @EmmaV wait,  you want a gui way of doing this?  why the bash tag?   and -  why would not find be suitable (just to get a explanation)  thanks for providing the details by the way! //Best wishes   (A short solution would be to use a file browser and just hold shift while selecting ) but I have no idea what you want to achieve - you can find the files with ls **(so you are inside the terminal)** what do you mean by (..)"and then copy and paste them into the terminal" ?   
Edit: read your comment below:  **`*`would include everything, not only zip files, and only in the current directory**

Comment: What I want to do is extract several files in the same command. I do not want to extract all of the files in the directory. I could easily extract them all by using `*` to match them all. What I want to do is not possible in the terminal alone, so I want to know whether I can use a GUI (e.g. a file manager) to select multiples files and export the list of selected files into the terminal.

Comment: @EmmaV, you can replace `-exec` with `-ok` here for `find` to prompt you for each file whether you want to unzip it or not.

Answer (score 0):

With bash, you can use [glob-expand-word](https://superuser.com/a/861145/) (`C-x *`) to perform a glob expansion and then use edit-and-execute-command (`C-x C-e`) to edit the command in your default editor:

> edit-and-execute-command (`C-x C-e`)
>
> Invoke an editor on the current command line, and execute the
> result as shell commands.  Bash attempts to invoke `$VISUAL`,
> `$EDITOR`, and emacs as the editor, in that order.

You therefore could type `unzip *` without pressing `Enter`, then press `C-x *` followed by `C-x C-e`, edit the expanded command to your liking, and then execute the command.

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers are insane; if this is a one-off, just struggle through manually entering file names. Otherwise, if it's a consistent need, determine a pattern, write a solution and version control as your requirements evolve.

Here is a directory with some log files

```bsh
~ $ ls /var/log | wc -l
46
```

I am only interested in `wifi` and `system` logs for some daily aggregate blah blah.

```bsh
~ $ ls /var/log/system* /var/log/wifi* | wc -l
22
```

Create a "Daily Aggregate Blah" strategy and commit (not shown).

```bsh
$ ls /var/log/system* /var/log/wifi* | wc -l
22
~ $ mkdir /tmp/selectstrategies
~ $ pushd /tmp/selectstrategies/
/tmp/selectstrategies ~
/tmp/selectstrategies $ printf "%s\n" "/var/log/system*" "/var/log/wifi*" | tee /dev/stderr >StrategyDailyAggregrate
/var/log/system*
/var/log/wifi*
```

Write small utility script to perform whatever task using a strategy file and commit to repo (not shown).

```
$ cat ./select.sh 
#!/bin/sh
set -eu

<$1 xargs -t  sh -c 'ls $@' -
```

Run

```bsh
$ ./select.sh StrategyDailyAggregrate 
sh -c 'ls $@' - '/var/log/system*' '/var/log/wifi*'
/var/log/system.log             /var/log/wifi.log.0.bz2
...
```

This was off the top of my head, but you get the point; if you need a bespoke solution, just write a simple, dirty and quick mvp. Iterate if needed, but no bells, no whistles.

Comment: I can't determine a pattern because the file names are arbitrary and they vary.

Comment: @EmmaV Dude, don't be so literal; by pattern, I mean some acceptable strategy. Above I grouped arbitrary files by a made up strategy, which is that I need to aggregate those logs and ship somewhere, yada yada. If the filenames are arbitrary, identify some overlap or repeated usage and build something simple that will cut down on manual entry and repition as much as possible. As you can see from the answers, there isnt a silver bullet, so you're not going to be able to avoid building something.